# Counting Backwards With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to import photos from a local file on my computer to my HTML file. I have managed to do this but it goes in ascending order. I have tried to add a variable

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready( function() {

 $("span").each( function(i) {
  $(this).append("<img src='Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-"+(++i)+".JPG' 
/>");   
 });

});
```

HTML

```
<span class="Images"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `length` of the `span` collection first, and then insert the image at `length - i`:

```
const $spans = $("span");
const { length } = $spans;
$spans.each(function(i) {
  $(this).append("<img src='Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-" + (length - i) + ".JPG' />");
});
```

Comment: I need to find out the number of files in the directory because there are more images in the folder.

Comment: There's no way to do that elegantly, client-side; either hard-code the number of files, or use a server-side language to count them and generate the appropriate number of `<span>`s dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try by running the loop in descending order

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let getAllSpans = $('span');
  let getSpanLength = $('span').length;
  for (let i = getSpanLength; i > 0; i--) {
    getAllSpans[i].append('<img src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-"' + i + '".JPG">')

  }
});

<span class="Images"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce "i" using length of span using **Jquery**, take a look over the code below.

```js
let valuez;
$("span").each( function(i) {
  valuez = $('span').length;
   console.log(valuez - i);
 });
function test(){
  valuez = $('span').length;
  console.log(valuez);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
<span>five</span>
```